# How to avoid race condition in different blocks in CUDA

Tags: cuda, grid, race-condition

I am writing a function in CUDA that divides set of unsorted points in a 3D grid. Based on the bounds of the point set, I can find the coordinate of every point and write it in an array within the grid cell.

I launch kernal with threads equal to number of points by dividing them in different blocks for max thread count.

Now each thread finds its coordinate and write the point in the cell, but other threads within same or different block can also compute same coordinate at same time. The code fails here because of race condition.

I read about atomics, locks and critical section but these synchronizations are used within a thread block only, that is unlikely in my case.

Any suggestions please ?

My initial guess is I need to sort the points based on distance of grid cell size, and launch kernal with each block equal to size of grid cell

Answer (score 2):

Atomics can work on the global memory and synchronize between blocks.  The only issue here is performance.  Depending on how much of the run time is taken up by just performing the writes to memory you may get slower code than just doing it in serial on the CPU.  Atomics are slow.  Maybe try to rethink the problem.